# Number generator not printing out expected first number in C

Tags: c, multithreading, numbers, pthreads, generator

So I have this generator, and the first number that should be outputted is 1804289383.

However, I am getting a number of 134519520, and sometimes, the last few digits will vary, but it is usually around this number.

Any idea why?  I've had similar code print out the desired number, but this won't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define MAX_NUM 10
#define MAX_RAND_NUM 100
#define SIZE 10

pthread_mutex_t the_mutex;
pthread_cond_t cond;
int buffer[SIZE];
int num_of_items = 0;

void *producer(void *ptr)
{   
    int i  = 0;
    int rand_num = 0;
    int rear = 0;   
    srandom((unsigned int)0);


        rand_num = random();
    pthread_mutex_lock(&the_mutex);
    while (num_of_items = SIZE) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&the_mutex);
    }//end of while loop
      buffer[rear] = rand_num;
      rear = (rear + 1) % SIZE;
      num_of_items +=1;
      printf("Producer on loop %d it stored %d \n",i,rand_num);
      pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&the_mutex);

        pthread_exit(0);
}

void *consumer(void *ptr)
{       int i  = 0;
        int rand_num = 0;
    int front = 0;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&the_mutex);
        while (num_of_items == 0) pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&the_mutex);
            printf("Consumer on loop %d it stored %d \n",i,buffer);
        //buffer[0] = 0;
        front = (front + 1) % SIZE;
        num_of_items -= 1;
            pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&the_mutex);

            pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   pthread_t pro,con;
   pthread_mutex_init(&the_mutex,0);
   pthread_cond_init(&cond,0);

   pthread_create(&con,0,consumer,0);
   pthread_create(&pro,0,producer,0);
   pthread_join(pro,0);
   pthread_join(con,0);
   pthread_cond_destroy(&cond);

   pthread_mutex_destroy(&the_mutex);
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's not obvious from the code above why you would expect 1804289383 in particular. Can you provide further information on why you need / expect that particular number?

Comment: I'm making a generator that requires that to be the first number per my assignment.  Now when I execute this code, the program just hangs, and I haven't been able to figure out why.

Comment: For one thing, the loop "while (num_of_items = SIZE)" will loop forever - you are assigning, not comparing values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
printf("Consumer on loop %d it stored %d \n",i,buffer);
```

`buffer` decays to a pointer, but you're trying to print it out as an `int`. That big number you're getting is an integer representation of an address. Perhaps you meant to do `buffer[i]` or something.

This looks kind of suspicious, too:

```
while (num_of_items = SIZE)
```

Possibly that should be an `==`.

If your compiler wasn't warning you about both of these things, you should maybe look for a better one, or turn up your warning levels.

Comment: I swear, it's always a rookie mistake. Thank you!